# Highlight a specific text in view page depending on URL id

Tags: javascript, jquery, codeigniter-3

How should I highlight the text in view from the URL link with id match to that particular id or text?
I have some 50 list out of that I need to highlight that particular id or text

I don't know whether I should write in **jquery** or with **codeigniter 3.**

> Eg.
>  localhost/example/admin/home/CL00074

[image]
Here is the pic which I want to highlight.

If you didn't understand, please let me know.

[image]

Check for refferal

Comment: Show us what you've tried.

Comment: i just wrote php tags like segment 3 match with that id. but im getting error. i have not tired with jquery because im not understand what to use over their

Comment: i have added 2 image please check. here in the url ink CL00074 is not dynamic.Before that my task is to find the paticular id in which page is it <br>For tracing that i use search option. From search im passing parmaeter before it look like this http://localhost/example/admin/home/  and after passing parameter like this below http://localhost/example/admin/home/CL00074<br>.
with this url [CL00074] links im highlight that id[CL00074] .Any help is much appreciate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably use Code Igniter's the [URI library](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html), it'd look something like this:

> $this->uri->segment(n)

But since this was a jQuery question, you'd use a hash and target it that way:

**Update your routing:** localhost/example/admin/home#CL00074

```
// if hash exists, check and highlight
if (window.location.hash) {
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');

    $('td[id='+ hash +']').addClass('selected');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibility two

1. This is use Segment 
   Follow [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/uri.html)

2.This is use Route
Follow [link](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/routing.html)

Add to script config/route.php

$route['admin/home/(:any)'] = 'Controllername/functionname/$1';

Answer (score 0):

Say your link would be localhost/example/admin/home#CL00074 and your id goes into the html like this:

```
<div id="CL00074">

</div>
```

, you could use only css to highlight or style that particular element (div, h1, li or whatever) of the page. 
Use `:target` css identifier:

```
:taget{
    color: black;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply @Vali S . but here the id will change if i check with another id CL00096 then how should i make work.

Comment: It's in the way you write your links. If the page changes, so does the #id part does, right? You must take care that the targeted html element should have the right id attribute too.